# How do I pass custom SQL queries to a MySQL database outside of app.js? (Express, Node, Pug architecture)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I can run queries in my app.js, but I can't figure out how to run custom queries in other webpages. (i.e user fills out a form then we send that as a sql query).

any ideas?

Comment: welcome to SO, please provide some example code depicting your case and needs, we are a community of programmers and understand code better than ideas :P

Answer (score 0):

Could you add an example form and how you want to use that?
I suppose you have an HTML `<form>` and it posts the data to the back-end when the form is submitted. And you get the data using a basic API. Then create your template SQL query strings and make them run SQL queries. You can create that custom SQL queries by concatenating strings or using template string literals. Example:

```
`INSERT INTO users VALUES ( ${id}, '${username}','${email}','${password}', ${age})`
```

But make sure that strings like username or password don't include ' character. So as a precaution, convert ' characters to \' characters using 'string'.replace()\